# Changelogs of many packages not available

Tags: package-management

I noticed a few weeks ago that some changelogs of packages that had been
updated were not available (and still aren't). "Not available" means that
they're not accessible using aptitude (Shift+C) and a web browser just shows
error 404.

Examples:

- php5: http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/php5
- sudo: http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/sudo
- snmp: http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/snmp
- openssl: http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/openssl

(and some libs that said packages depend on)

I know that not all available packages have changelogs but the ones I mentioned
have had until recently.
Though the above packages are linked particularly to Ubuntu Hardy, the
changelogs of all other LTS versions (Lucid and Precise) are missing, too.

The subject says "many" and not "all" changelogs are missing. The changelog of
linux-libc-dev is available: http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/linux-libc-dev

I opened a discussion regarding this topic on the German Ubuntuusers Forum:

- http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/changelog-der-pakete-nicht-mehr-verfuegbar/

What is going on? Did I miss something?

I also sent an e-mail to the mailing list ubuntu-devel-discuss (on June 4th) but obviously the mail wasn't forwarded to the list. That's why I opened this topic.

Answer (score 0):

This was [bug 1005985](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1005985) and appears to have been fixed now.